# Runtime impacts when styling web compontents

Tags: css, browser, web-component

Consider the following web components Foo and Bar. How does the browser behave in both cases when I have very many instances of Foo and Bar respectively on a page. Which approach is more performant? I suspect that with Bar, the browser loads the CSS only once and then parses it only once. With Foo's approach, it doesn't have to load anything, but it does have to re-parse for each instance of Foo. Is that correct?

```js
window.customElements.define('my-foo', class Foo extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <style>
         p {
           color: red;
         }
         // more styles go here
      </style>
      <p>Foo</p>
    `;
  }
});

window.customElements.define('my-bar', class Bar extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/my/cdn/bar.css">
      <p>Bar</p>
    `;
  }
});
```

Comment: FYI, no need for ``this.#content`` at all. ``attachShadow({mode:"open"})`` gives you ``this.shadowRoot`` for free. And there is more: [Web Components Lesson 102](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/web-component-102-the-5-lessons-after-learning-web-components-101-h9p)

Comment: I am no CSS buff! but I would say in Bar the **CSS file itself** is cached by the Browser (unless the server prevented caching) But I would say it is parsed (and that is the renderblocking/costly part) again to CSSOM